# Read MS SQL Server View to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read a MS SQL Server view to a pandas dataframe.  At first I thought it was a table, so I wrote the following code (tables/views, server, database, ID and password have been changed to remove proprietary information):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib
from datetime import date

today = date.today().isformat()

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                 + 'SERVER=mssql_server;DATABASE=database;UID='
                                 + 'user_id;PWD=password')
engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}')

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    # Read data and store in pandas dataframe.
    df1 = pd.read_sql_table('dbo.view1', conn)
    df2 = pd.read_sql_table('dbo.view2', conn)
    df3 = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM dbo.view3 WHERE date=' + today, conn)
```

but it resulted in the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 243, in read_sql_table
    meta.reflect(only=[table_name], views=True)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4261, in reflect
    "in %r%s: (%s)" % (bind.engine, s, ", ".join(missing))

InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine(mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=mssql_server;DATABASE=database;UID=user_id;PWD=password): (dbo.view1)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-89-bbb0170e1399>", line 1, in <module>
    df1 = pd.read_sql_table('dbo.view1', engine)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 245, in read_sql_table
    raise ValueError("Table {name} not found".format(name=table_name))

ValueError: Table dbo.view1 not found
```

That was when I found out I was trying to load a view and not a table, so I changed the code to:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib
from datetime import date

today = date.today().isformat()

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                 + 'SERVER=mssql_server;DATABASE=database;UID='
                                 + 'user_id;PWD=password')
engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}')

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    # Read data and store in pandas dataframe.
    df1 = pd.read_sql('dbo.view1', conn)
    df2 = pd.read_sql('dbo.view2', conn)
    df3 = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM dbo.view3 WHERE date=' + today, conn)
```

Which resulted in the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The request for procedure 'view1' failed because 'view1' is a view object. (2809) (SQLExecDirectW)")


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-76-6b8d4a0d911d>", line 1, in <module>
    df1 = pd.read_sql('dbo.view1', engine)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 436, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1218, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1087, in execute
    return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2182, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 976, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1149, in _execute_text
    parameters,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The request for procedure 'view1' failed because 'view1' is a view object. (2809) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: dbo.view1]
```

I've tried searching for the answer but either haven't found it, or am looking in the wrong place.  Can reading a view to a pandas dataframe be done?  If so, what am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `read_sql_query` for all three? e.g., `pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.view1", ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing it this way?

```
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=LAPTOP-CEDUMII6;"
                        "Database=TestDB;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = cnxn.cursor()
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM myTable1'))
```